# Double integral $\int_a^b \int_a^y e^{y^2-x^2}dxdy$

Tags: definite-integrals, error-function

I am trying to find a numerical way to compute the following double integral
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b \int_a^y e^{y^2-x^2}dxdy
\end{equation}

One attempt I've made is to express the inner integral in terms of the error-function
\begin{equation}
\int_a^y e^{-x^2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(\operatorname{erf}y - \operatorname{erf}a)
\end{equation}
but found no nice way to compute integrals of $e^{y^2}\operatorname{erf}y$.

Comment: Do you need to be able to do this for all $a$ and $b$ or is only some subset of the reals of interest?

Comment: For any real numbers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Substitution $u=y+x$, $v=y-x$, and then inner integration over $u$, results in $$\frac12\int_0^{b-a}\big(e^{v(2b-v)}-e^{v(2a+v)}\big)\frac{dv}{v}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let x=r$cost$ and y=r$sint$ then $y^2-x^2$=$-r^2cos2t$ so our integral transforms to ;

$\iint e^{y^2-x^2} dxdy$=$\iint e^{-r^2cos2t} r dr dt$

which can be computed with u-substiution.Let $r^2$=u then

$\int e^{-r^2cos2t} r dr = 1/2 \int e^{-ucos2t} du$ =$\frac{1}{(-2cos2t)} e^{r^2}$

=$\iint e^{-r^2cos2t} r dr dt$=$\int \frac{1}{(-2cos2t)} e^{r^2} dt $

which is just integral of sec

Comment: Not that easy. Integration over $r$ will have the upper limit depending on $t$. (You don't even mention the domain of integration.)

Comment: i did not mention the domain of integration because i dont know how to use mathjax :)

Comment: Hmm, things are even worse; $a<x<y<b$ results in $r_1(t)<r<r_2(t)$ with some weird $r_1$ and $r_2$, and your final integral will have $e^{r_2^2(t)}-e^{r_1^2(t)}$ in place of "$e^{r^2}$".